# Relative pathway works to display images in CSS file but not in Javascript file

Tags: javascript, css, html, relative-path

Ok, going to rewrite this…

I have a project. It has 2 layers. Top layer is HTML5 animation (rollovers, slides etc). Bottom layer is kaleidoscope animation using images and CSS.

Bottom layer displays correctly. Top layer does not.

Client has requested that we use relative pathways.
Client has requested we use a strict directory structure of: Pages, Documents, PlusImages.

```
Pages= html/txt (where the css/javascript is attached in)
```

Documents= where the CSS and Javascript files are
PlusImages= where all the images are stored

Here's the issue: The images are NOT displaying for the top layer which is called by a javascript file. The program that generated this script is called Tumult Hype

How can I correct this? I thought about adding ../PlusImages/imagename.png to the agilent_hype_generated_script.js file.

```
Here is the pathway client wants to use:
```

http://www.XYZ.com/en-US/Products-Services/Services/

HTML File code connecting the CSS and JS files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/en-US/Products-Services/Services/Documents/main.css"  type="text/css" media="all">

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/en-US/Products-Services/Services/Documents/agilent_hype_generated_script.js?55531"></script>
```

main.css:

```
.kal_main{background-image:url(/en-US/Products-Services/Services/PlusImages/Animation-Background.png);overflow:hidden;width:920px;height:510px;margin:auto}


agilent_hype_generated_script.js:
```

`(function(){(function k(){var h="Agilent.hyperesources",e="Agilent",d="agilent_hype_container";    if(false==!1)try{for(var     f=document.getElementsByTagName("script"),b=0;b<f.length;b++){var a=f[b].src;if(null!=a&&-1!=a.indexOf("agilent_hype_generated_script.js")){h=a.substr(0,a.lastIndexOf("/"));break}}}catch(n){}if(false==!1&&null==window.HYPE_316)null==window.HYPE_dtl_316?(window.HYPE_dtl_316=[],window.HYPE_dtl_316.push(k),e=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],d=document.createElement("script"),
b=navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE (\d+\.\d+)/),b=parseFloat(b&&b[1])||null,d.type="text/javascript",d.src=h+"/"+(null!=b&&10>b?"HYPE.ie.js":"HYPE.js")+"?hype_version=316",e.appendChild(d)):window.HYPE_dtl_316.push(k);else{f=window.HYPE.documents;if(null!=f[e]){a=1;b=e;do e=""+b+"-"+a++;while(null!=f[e]);for(var c=document.getElementsByTagName("div"),a=!1,b=0;b<c.length;b++)if(c[b].id==d&&null==c[b].getAttribute("HYP_dn")){var a=1,g=d;do d=""+g+"-"+a++;while(null!=document.getElementById(d));c[b].id=
d;a=!0;break}if(!1==a)return}for(var a=new HYPE_316,c=[],c=[],g={},l={},b=0;b<c.length;b++)try{l[c[b].identifier]=c[b].name,g[c[b].name]=eval("(function(){return "+c[b].source+"})();")}catch(m){a.log(m),g[c[b].name]=function(){}}a.z_a({R:5,S:0,aI:0,T:0,bG:3,aJ:0,bH:2,aK:0,X:0,bI:3,aL:0,Y:1,bJ:3,bK:3,bL:3,a:0,b:0,c:0,d:0,aS:0,e:3,bQ:0,aT:0,f:2,g:5,bR:2,aU:0,bS:"NumberValueTransformer",aV:0,aW:3,A:5,l:2,aX:0,B:5,m:5,C:5,aY:2,n:5,D:5,E:0,aZ:0,G:5,t:0,bA:5,RotationAngle:2,tX:4,bB:0,M:0,N:0,bC:0,tY:4,O:0,P:0,Q:0});a.z_b({"25":{p:1,n:"../PlusImages/Overlay-Type-4.png",g:"127",t:"@1x"},"18":{p:1,n:"../PlusImages/Overlay-Type-3.png",g:"86",t:"@1x"},"10":{p:1,n:"../PlusImages/03-over-1.png",g:"101",t:"@1x"},`

(you can see how the images are referenced above) - ../PlusImages/imagename.png    Will this work or am I missing something??

Comment: What folder is your javascript file in?

Comment: If you could post the code in question it would probably clear things up quite a bit.

Comment: CSS file and JS file are in the Documents folder. They are being called by a html/text file in the Pages folder. All images are in the PlusImages folder. Client requires this directory structure

Comment: Put a tab character or at least four spaces in front of all code so that it gets formatted properly.

Answer (score 1):

Alright your text is a bit confusing, but I will give this a shot.

It sounds like your javascript file is being linked into an HTML page? If this is the case, then the path from the javascript to the images should be the same as it is for your HTML since that's where it's being run from.